# Dsplaying unicode in a Form

Tags: vba, excel

After much trial and error ,and with assistance from the community, the ability to use Unicode in a form has not been very successful. So the question is. Is there a method to have the ability to use Unicode within a form ? primarily in textbox control were a currency symbol like the Peso symbol(₱) will appear in a textbox. there are various ways to have it on a worksheet but in a  form is an allusive task.

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: Using Tahoma as Font, I have no problems to show the ₱ in a label or textbox, add the Peso sign via Alt+8369 or via Cut&Paste into the Editbox or via code using `ChrW(8369)`. Using Excel2016 on W10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After much trial and error ,and with assistance from the community, the ability to use Unicode in a form has not been very successful.

Says who? :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Text = ChrW(8369)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How can I concantanate it into this once my code has calculated?  Private Sub Txtunitcost_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

  Me.txtTotal.Value = CDbl(Me.txtQty.Value) * CDbl(Me.txtUnitCost.Value)
    txtTotal.Value = Format(txtTotal.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
    txtUnitCost.Value = Format(txtUnitCost.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))

Comment: You mean like this? `txtTotal.Value = ChrW(8369) & Format(txtTotal.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))`

Comment: I OWE YOU A BREWSKEE! thank you thank you had a comma in the wrong place

Comment: I owe you a beer. If I  selected the wrong answer , sorry.

Comment: yes it was by mistake, I corrected it I think. your answer is the one that I truly needed and used.

Answer (score 3):

[image: screen shot]

Among other methods, you could:

- copy & paste Unicode into a textbox, or,
- or use `ChrW` to use a specific character like this:

  ```
  UserForm1.TextBox1 = ChrW(8369)  'puts a ₱ in the text box.
  ```

Note that in most cases the VBA Editor (VBE) won't display Unicode (so copy/pasting the above code into your VBE will replace the `₱` with a `?`).

By the way CodePoints is a handy site for finding/identifying unicode symbols. Type *whatever you're looking for* in the search bar, or copy & paste from a website to find out more.

Also, note that all symbols that appear on your system **may or or may not** render properly on others.